# file.write appends a new line automatically in python

Tags: python

I am trying to append multiple words with a word in python for writing it to a file as below :

```
out_file.write(words+'Positive')
```

I am not using `\n` here. But the output turns out to be in 2 lines as below :

```
It is awesome awesome.
Positive
```

What I am expecting is `It is awesome. Positive`. Please help.

Comment: `file.write()` will not append anything for you. The newline was already there, in the value of `word`.

Comment: Do  `print repr(word)`  to see if there is any  `\n`  in that variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string_with_2_lines = words + 'Positive'
string_altered = string_with_2_lines.replace('\n',' ')

>>>It is awesome. Positive
```

Comment: When I am using sentence, it is getting split into single word @Micolho

Comment: @ViVi if you are splitting a string, you will probably receive a list with words. If that is the case, can you show us the value of the `words` variable ?

Comment: Its worked like magicaly

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
words = 'It is awesome awesome.'

with open('sample.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(words + ' ' + 'Positive')
```

Here is your output in the .txt:

```
It is awesome awesome. Positive
```